# Trigonometry - parameter

Tags: trigonometry

For which real parameter values $n$ equation $\frac{4n+3}{6}-\sin4x\cos4x-(n+\frac{2}{3})\sin(4x-\frac{\pi}{4})=0$ have exactly three solutions for $x \in [\frac{\pi}{16}, \frac{5\pi}{16}]$

Well I rewrite this equation as $4n+3-6\sin4x\cos4x-(3n+2)\sqrt2(\sin4x-\cos4x)=0 $ , but I don't know what's next

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I apologize for the length of the answer and my incapability to minimize answer as HINT only.

Squaring should be avoided as it immediately introduces [Extraneous](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extraneous_and_missing_solutions) roots

Using $\sin2A=2\sin A\cos A$

$$4n+3-3\sin8x-(6n+4)\sin\left(4x-\frac\pi4\right)=0$$

Let $\displaystyle 4x-\frac\pi4=y$

$\displaystyle\implies(i)8x=\frac\pi2+2y,\sin8x=\sin\left(\frac\pi2+2y\right)=\cos2y=1-2\sin^2y $

and $(ii)$ as $\displaystyle\frac\pi{16}\le x\le\frac{5\pi}{16},\frac\pi4\le4x\le\frac{5\pi}4$
$\displaystyle\implies0\le4x-\frac\pi4\le\pi\implies0\le y\le\pi \ \ \ \ (2)$

So, we have $\displaystyle 4n+3-3(1-2\sin^2y)-(6n+4)\sin y=0 $

$\displaystyle\implies6\sin^2y-(6n+4)\sin y+4n=0 \  \ \  \ (1)$

$\displaystyle\implies\sin y=n,\frac23 $

If $y_1$ is a solution of $(1)$, so will be $\pi-y_1$ as $\sin(\pi-B)=\sin B$

Then we shall have either two or four solutions unless for one solution $\displaystyle y_1=\pi-y_1\iff y_1=\frac\pi2\implies \sin y_1=1$

$\displaystyle\sin y=-1$ also makes  $\sin(\pi-y)=\sin y$ But from $(2),\sin y\ge0$

We already have two solutions due to $\displaystyle\sin y=\frac23$

So, $n$ must be $1$

Comment: @Mark, how about this?

Comment: thank you very much for the detailed explanation

Comment: @Mark, my pleasure. Its nice to know that I could make the idea clear

Comment: but shouldn't there be in first line $(6a+4)$ against $(3a+2)$ ??

Comment: @Mark, thanks for your feedback. Please find the edited version

Comment: how have you got $\sin y=n,\frac{2}{3}$ ? because I can't figure it out. When I calculate $\delta=4(9n^2+12n-20)$ and don't know what next

Comment: @Mark, If you have meant determinant by $\delta$ it is actually $$(6n+4)^2-4\cdot6\cdot4n=(6n-4)^2$$

Answer (score 1):

Here is how. Starting from the equation

$$ 4n+3-6\sin4x\cos4x-(3n+2)\sqrt2(\sin4x-\cos4x)=0. $$

We write it in the form

$$ \implies 4n+3-6\sin4x\cos4x=(3n+2)\sqrt2(\sin4x-\cos4x)$$

> $$ \implies (4n+3-6\sin4x\cos4x)^2=( (3n+2)\sqrt2(\sin4x-\cos4x))^2. $$

Now, square both sides of the last equation, simplify, and then use the identity

> $$  \cos^2(4x) = 1 -\sin^2(4x), $$

that results in a quadratic equation in $\sin(4x)$ which you need to solve.